# 98 WRX EJ20 Cam or belt skipped teeth by hand

Tags: subaru, timing-belt, timing, wrx, valve-timing

I'm doing the timing on a 1998 WRX EJ20 and I was trying to undo the crank bolt again (I'd already taken it off to remove the timing covers then reinstalled once the covers were off to align the timing marks) and I was using a socket and ratchet to hold the top right cam (facing the engine) in place while I tried to undo the crank bolt. While doing this the cam or belt skipped forward on it's own and went out of timing. The crank was still in position. I then turned the crank twice trying to line up the markings again but they were all over the place. I went slowly a bit further but felt resistance so I stopped fearing for the valves. I then took the spark plugs out and there is still resistance.

Can I just remove the belt and turn the crank by hand back to it's timing mark then put all the cams back into position? Or is there a risk that I will bend valves considering there currently seems to be resistance?

Thanks